# Displaying a large image from the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have problems with displaying a large image from the list. I choose from the list of image categories, and then 4 small pictures are displayed (in CSS I set `max-width: 10%; height; auto`). Then I click on the photo and display it in a new window.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  const imgFromTable = selectTable[i];
  console.log(selectTable);
  let myImg = document.createElement('div');
  myImg.className = 'myImg';
  myImg.innerHTML = `<a href="${imgFromTable}" target="_blank"><img src="${imgFromTable}" ></a>`;
  results.appendChild(myImg);
```

In the results I want the image to be displayed in full size elsewhere (eg. in a div) on this page after click.

Comment: for that, you need to send flag for the image is large or small
according to that flag, you can dispay an image

Comment: can you post the full code with HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this

```js
var selectTable = [
  "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png",
  "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/arctichare.png",
  "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/baboon.png",
  "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/barbara.bmp"
]

var results = document.querySelector("#results")

var showImage = url => document.querySelector("#view").src = url


selectTable.forEach(imgFromTable => {
  let myImg = document.createElement('div');
  myImg.className = 'myImg';
  myImg.innerHTML = `<a onclick="showImage('${imgFromTable}')"><img src="${imgFromTable}" ></a>`;
  results.appendChild(myImg);
})
```

```css
.myImg {
  max-width: 10%;
  height: auto;
}

.myImg img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="results">
</div>
<img id="view">
```